# Static member and inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, static

I have a class with a member `m_preferences` (a vector containing assocation between word and features).

In this class the `m_preferences` is not static and thus any instance of the class has its specific `m_preferences`.

```
class Base{

private:

    Preferences m_preferences;

public:
...

}
```

I then created a derived class where `m_preferences` become static because I wanted that each new instance of this class share the same data for preferences no matter what happens.

```
class Derived: public Base{

private:

    static Preferences m_preferences;

public:
...

}
```

I got a linking error.

Is it possible to do what I want to do (transforming a non-static member into a static one through inheritance)?

If not what are the philosophy behind this impossibility?  Was it planned?

Thank you,

Sincerely,

Ronan

Comment: What are the objects?  Seems like you may have a design problem and you're running into the wrong path, hitting this wall.

Answer (score 7):

You can't stop every instance of `Base` - including every instance of `Derived` - from having a per-instance Preferences member variable as this is guaranteed by the definition of the Base class.

What you have done is added a new static `Preferences` member to the `Derived` class, which means that as well as a per-instance `Preferences` member associated with the base class you also have a global `Preferences` instance shared between all the `Derived` instances.

Because you have used the same name for these two members, in the context of a `Parent` member function, using the indentifier `m_preferences` will refer to the global shared instances unless you qualify it as in `Base::m_preferences`.

Your link error is probably because you need to provide a definition of `Derived::m_preferences` in one of your translation units.

e.g. in some.cpp, outside of any function bodies:

```
Preferences Derived::m_preferences;
```

Answer (score 4):

If I'm reading you right, you want to define a hierarchy of objects which will have either a static, or an individual, instance variable Preferences. Try this?

```
class Base
{
  virtual ~Base();
  virtual Preferences& MyPreferences() =0;
};

class DerivedA: public Base
{
public:
  virtual ~DerivedA();
  virtual Preferences& MyPreferences() { return m_preferences; }

private:
  Preferences m_preferences;
};

class DerivedB: public Base
{
public:
  virtual ~DerivedB();
  virtual Preferences& MyPreferences() { return preferences; }

private:
  static Preferences preferences;
};

Preferences DerivedB::preferences;
```

"Transforming", as [Ali Shafai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24351/ali-shafai) said it too, is not possible. The problem here is that "static" members are properties of the class itself rather than of individual objects, while virtual declarations and inheritance are about handling individual objects that may not be of the same class, uniformly, at a higher level of abstraction.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: you aren't using inheritance properly.

Long answer: You defined Base as being a type with individual Preferences. If Derived does not meet the "is-a" qualification (Derived is a type that also has per-instance preferences), than it should not inherit from Base.

Perhaps a better design (?):

```
class NotDerivedAnymore
{

private:

    static Base m_base;

public:
...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is **by design** you cannot change the **signature** of a member while inheriting it.

Answer (score 1):

You are breaking the **[is-a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a)** rule of inheritance.

You are stating that `Base` is a type that has its own `Preferences` member, and you are stating that `Derived` **is a** `Base`.

It appears that your `Base` and `Derived` objects share some qualities, but not as a direct inheritance

I believe this well get the result you want

```
class TrueBase{ 
    // Put data and functionality here that really is common for both types.
  private:

    virtual Preferences& get_preferences() = 0;
};

class Base : public TrueBase{
  private:

    virtual Preferences& get_preferences()
    {
        return m_preferences;
    }

    Preferences m_preferences;
};


class Derived: public TrueBase{  
  private:

    virtual Preferences& get_preferences()
    {
        return m_preferences;
    }

    static Preferences m_preferences;   
};
```